# Is there Bounded (Maybe a) for un-Bounded a?

Tags: haskell

I have a `Foldable` of `Integer`s which are unbounded and thus I cannot apply a `Max` fold to it.

Would it make sense to define `Max` instance of `Nothing` when a value does not exist? There is `Ord a => Semigroup (Max a)` but I cannot find `Max` instance for `(Ord a) => Option a`.

See [foldReduce](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.7/reducers-3.12.2/src/Data.Semigroup.Reducer.html#foldReduce) for more context.

Comment: There is the class `Foldable1` from [semigroupoids](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.2.2/docs/Data-Semigroup-Foldable-Class.html) that seems like it might be what you want.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-11.8/lens-4.16.1/Control-Lens-Internal-Fold.html#v:NoMax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The monoid-extras package offers [Data.Monoid.Inf](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monoid-extras-0.4.4/docs/Data-Monoid-Inf.html) for one-sided bounds. The extended-reals package offers [Data.ExtendedReal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/extended-reals-0.2.3.0/docs/Data-ExtendedReal.html), which is sometimes more convenient if you want to add both bounds in one shot without privileging one or the other's `Monoid` instance or want a fresh `Bounded` instance that doesn't rely on the underlying type being `Bounded`.